# Python BeatifulSoup scrape a dynamic container

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some flashcards from [this](https://learninglink.oup.com/access/content/neuroscience-sixth-edition-student-resources/neuroscience-6e-chapter-1-flashcards?previousFilter=tag_chapter-01) website, but I am having a few problems. Below a snippet of my code:

```
# point to the right link and chapter
url_main = r'https://learninglink.oup.com/access/content/neuroscience-sixth-edition-student-resources/neuroscience-6e-chapter-1-flashcards?previousFilter=tag_chapter-'
chapter = '01'
url_main = url_main + chapter

# get source
html = requests.get(url_main).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
```

If I inspect the page on Chrome, I can see that the information I am looking for is in class="box1text". So I do:

```
# get class
text = bs.find(class_ = "box1text" )
```

However, when I print this 'text' variable I get:

```
<span aria-live="assertive" class="box1text"></span>
```

And no mention of the text I am looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I would like to know how to interact with this container and its buttons, but I don't even know where to start from. My ideal output would be a dictionary containing all the keywords and the associated answers (so, front and back of the card for each flashcard), but to do so I need to be able to interact with this container. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: modern pages use JavaScript to add elements but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript - but this works (much) slower - but code can interact like normal human. OR you should use method described by @hidden_machine - and it may work faster then normal scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but there is actually a better way to go about this.

If you go into devTools sidebar of your browser, and examine the network log,
you would see that there is a Http request being sent to get all the flashcard info:[image: screenshot]

As you can see, all you need to do is mimic this http request by copying the request header and sending it.
Since I don't use python, i would just use cUrl on the windows command prompt.
You could do this too right now by `right clicking` on that exact request when the browser is open and clicking on `'copy as Curl(cmd)'` , and pasting whatever you get into the command prompt, and you should be getting the required text that you can easily read[image]

**Edit:**
Also, the site in your post doesn't require any additional paramters to be sent in the request, so you should be able to get away with just:

```
curl "https://learninglink.oup.com/protected/files/content/flashcardCsv/1512079199667-Neuroscience6e-ch01_flashcards.csv"
```

you can copy and paste this in cmd to verify for yourself

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can send http requests through almost any language as there are libraries(either inbuilt or external)  to do so. I don't know python, so i don't know the normal way to do this in python, but since you just have to write one http request to get all the flashcard info, it shouldn't take too long to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I only add to this answer: on page https://curl.trillworks.com/ you can convert `curl` to Python and other languages. Sometimes it may create incorrect code when curl need many options  but here should not be problem.

Comment: As you said it does not answer the original question, but it is a great and easier solution so +1 and accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add on, `copy as curl(cmd)` gives many annoying '^' at wrong places for windows. You have to edit it out to have the curl command work properly with cmd